# Tikz aligning elements by their anchor positions

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, alignment, anchor

i found a lot of information about the positioning on Nodes, but i couldn't really apply the solutions to my problem.

[image]

I have two nodes defined in a seperate file. The left one has an anchor RD1 and the right one has a variable amount of anchors named IN1,IN2,... The problem im trying to solve now is to align both of these anchors vertically, so that the line going from RD1 to IN1 is straight.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm,thick,label]
    \node [reg] (PC) at (0,0) {};
    \node [instmem] (INSTMEM) at (2,0) {};
    \node [regfile] (RF) [right=of INSTMEM] {};
    \node [extend] (EXT) [below=of RF] {};
    \node [mux,rotate=-90,anchor=IN2] (ALU) [right=of RF.RD1] {ALU};
    \node [datamem] (DATAMEM) [right=of ALU.OUT] {};
    %\node [mux,ports=4,delta=2] (ALU2) [below=of ALU] {ALU};
    \draw   (PC.PC) |- (INSTMEM.A)
            (INSTMEM.RD) |- node[midway,above right]{19:16}  (RF.A1) node[above]{RA1}
            (INSTMEM.RD) |- node[midway,above right]{15:12} (RF.A3)
            (INSTMEM.RD) |- node[midway,above right]{11:0} (EXT.IN)
            (RF.RD1) -- +(1,0) -| (ALU.IN2) node[above]{SrcA}
            (EXT.OUT) node[below]{ExtImm} |- (ALU.IN1) node[above]{SrcB}
            (ALU.OUT) -| (DATAMEM.A);
\end{tikzpicture}\\
```

Heres the code i am using for this picture right now (there are more elements to the left and right).
I tried several things now, like repositioning the west anchor or shifting the whole node. But it seems a little bit too cluttered if i do so.

The best solution would probably look like `(ALU.IN1) right of (RF.RD1)` but i don't know how to go about all of this.

the complete code is at https://github.com/MrDiver/MicroArchLatex but isn't requiered to Answer the question. Because i just want to know how to align the two Anchors vertically

greetings Diver

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Could you post a complete code ? It would help readers reproduce your example, and make necessary changes to bring the required effect.

Comment: I added a link to the github repository with the complete code. Didn't want to paste 1000 lines of code in to question.

Comment: Thanks. Adding `,xshift=-3mm` after `rotate=-90` does the job temporarily... though it's a bad solution, and of course not generic.

Comment: Changing the anchor from `IN1` to `south`, say, does not seem to have any effect. Looking at your source file one sees a rather extensive node shape definition. Somewhere in it there might be a fundamental problem. Before posting here a code fragment that relies on over one thousand lines of code somewhere, in which the node anchors get defined in loops, I recommend going step by step and verifying that the most basic things work first. And then ask basic, self-contained questions if this does not work.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with the code in specific. If theres a solution to the problem then it should work for any node with anchors. It doesn't really matter if my code has an error and also basic things work perfectly fine and im 99% sure the anchor definitions are right. But i can also add that to the Question.

Comment: Try `\node [mux,rotate=-90,right=of RF.RD1,anchor=IN2] (ALU)  {ALU};`. When you do `right=of...` that sets `anchor=west`, so any `anchor` options has to be after the positioning option.

Comment: that actually worked. i always did the `anchor=IN1` first.

Comment: Order matters sometimes :) By the way, if you write `@<username>`, e.g. @MrDiver, the user is notified, only the post owner is notified of all comments. (And if I may, I do agree that it's better to post smaller, self-contained examples. If the problem can be demonstrated without 1000 lines of node definitions etc., why include it? It's easier to test and debug e.g. \documentclass[tikz]{standalone} \usetikzlibrary{positioning} \begin{document} \begin{tikzpicture} \node [draw] (a) {A}; \node [draw, anchor=south west] (b) [right=of a.north east] {B}; \end{tikzpicture} \end{document}`)